# Configure two switches from one terminal?

Tags: networking, switching

Hi this is a noob question I know, but I've forgotten how to configure two switches from one pc terminal. I'm guessing it has to do with vty. maybe assign one as vty 1 and the other as vty 0, but I'm not sure. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Enable VTY connections and remotely connect to the switches. I have added a quick example on how to enable VTY connections.

> ```
> SW1#conf t
> SW1(config)#line vty 0 15
> SW1(config-line)#logging synchronous 
> SW1(config-line)#exec-timeout 30 0
> SW1(config-line)#password (fill in)
> SW1(config-line)#login
> SW1(config-line)#end
> ```

2. If they're brand new, you should connect using a console cable.

Also check out the following [link](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ios-nx-os-software/ios-software-releases-110/45843-configpasswords.html), it provides some insight on **Telnet, Console and AUX Port Passwords on Cisco Routers Configuration**.